# Personal VPN Solutions

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I want to set up a VPN for my laptop to connect back at home so that I don't have to directly expose my desktop computer to the internet. Here is what I have:

```
Internet -> DD-WRT v24sp1-mega -> Desktop PC w/ Windows 7 Ultimate
                               -> MacBook w/ OSX 10.6
```

What would be the easiest thing to do? DD-WRT has PPTP and OpenVPN built in and Windows 7 has RRAS itself but thus far I've run into some problems. Are there any other alternatives, or suggestions on getting these to work?

#### PPTP

I tried setting up PPTP directly on DD-WRT using these [directions](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/PPTP_Server_Configuration). When I tried connecting using my external IP from the MacBook I just kept getting that the remote server did not respond.

#### OpenVPN

According to the instructions [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/VPN_%28the_easy_way%29_v24%2B#Enough_NVRAM_storage_space.3F) I don't have enough open nvram to set up OpenVPN.

#### RRAS

I got RRAS set up without a problem and can connect from the MacBook to the Windows 7 box while I'm on the same network. I port forwarded 1723 on the DD-WRT back to the Windows 7 box and made sure that PPTP Passthrough was enabled. Again, like PPTP, it just kept timing out.

Comment: Are you sure your isp itself isn't blocking this?

Comment: Heh, as it turns out I was testing via PDANet over my phone and that was the problem with RRAS and PPTP. Tried it from another real ISP and they worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) -- dead simple way to do personal VPN. I've been using it for years to keep my personal machines linked and love it.

If the goal is "just" to do remote control of the home PC you might look at something like the free flavor of [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/) as well.

Comment: I'd forgotten about Hamachi, I'll have to check it out again.

Comment: @Chris_K - Does Hamachi support password-based authentication on a per-connection basis, or certificate-based authentication?  My experience with Hamachi VPNs was that you needed to know the password to join the "group" (or whatever the terminology is), but that is a one-time exercise.  My recollection is that there was no authentication each time you want to connect.  Am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just port-forward 3389 to your desktop and use Remote Desktop for Mac? I understand you were concerned about security but this involves opening one port in the same way you were trying for the VPN solutions.

Comment: For that reason - security. 3389 is one of those ports that are normally scanned for and Windows doesn't really have a way to stop brute force attacks. Yes, I could change the port to something else but again, Windows doesn't really defend itself.